# Visual Composer is returning error after installing theme?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

My visual composer is not working. It is returning following error in the javascript console:

```
shortcodes_builder.js?ver=4.6.2:84 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

custom_views.js?ver=4.6.2:81 Uncaught TypeError: _.template(...).trim is not a function
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of visual composer ? As I recall this was present in older version of VC